# Crashlytics doesn't trigger onRegressed when a previously logged crash occurs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, crashlytics

I am trying to log all the errors from Firebase Crashlytics to my MongoDB database. When an error occurs for the first time the function below gets triggered successfully

```
exports.sendOnNew = functions.crashlytics.issue().onNew(issue => {

logmodel.create(issue, function(err) {
    if (err) 
    returnValue = handleError(err);
else
    returnValue = "Succeed";
});
return returnValue;
});
```

However, I expect that if the same error occurs again, it should trigger onRegressed, right? Well, it doesn't happen.

```
exports.sendOnRegressed = functions.crashlytics.issue().onRegressed(event => {
logmodel.create(event, function(err) {
    if (err) 
        returnValue = handleError(err);
    else
        returnValue = "Succeed";
});
return returnValue;
});
```

Is there anything wrong with my code above? It follows the same pattern from Google Docs. My functions are all successfully deployed, and doesn't show me an error or any clue in the logs.
By the way, I can see the error in the Crashlytics tab on Firebase. However, my event doesn't get triggered.
I appreciate any advice you can give.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/crashlytics-events):

> Regressed issue events trigger when an issue **reoccurs** after it's closed in Crashlytics.

It's not simply triggered on a second instance of the same crash.  The crash has to be previously closed in the console.  That's what a regression is: a occurrence of a crash after you think that you've fixed it already.

Comment: the problem is that when a NullPointerException occurs in somewhere in some class, I get it as a new issue. However, if this NullPointerException again occurs but this time in a different class or function, it doesn't get triggered.

Comment: What you're describing is not a regression.  It's just a different crash.  Not all NullPointerExceptions have the same root cause, which means they're not the same crash.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I have the same exception from two different roots in one app. I don't get onNew event triggered on the same exception from the different roots. The problem is that.